# ¿Cómo poner mensajitos en elementos específicos?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito colocar mensajitos en elementos del DOM, que dure solo unos segundos. ¿existe una librería?

Los mensajes deben mostrarse 1 por 1,(termina 1 empieza otro) cuando carga la pagina.

```html
<div>
  input 1 (necesito un mensaje por unos segundos)
</div>

<div>
  input 2 (necesito otro mensaje por unos segundos)
</div>

<span>
boton   (necesito el ultimo mensaje por unos segundos)
<span>
```

Comment: Cuando se debe de mostrar el mensaje: Cuando carga la página? Cuando pasa por encima el ratón? Cuando se lanza un evento? Y es necesario un número determinado de segundos o si por ejemplo el ratón esta por encima aparece pero se deja de estarlo deja de aparece.

Comment: Perdona no vi que lo actualizaste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
    var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
    
    visible(input1);  //el primero se hace visible cuando se carga la página.
    setTimeout(function(){invisible(input1)}, 3000);  //el primero se hace invisble después de 3 segundos.
    setTimeout(function(){visible(input2)}, 3000);  //el segundo se hace visible cuando pasan 3 segundos.
    setTimeout(function(){invisible(input2)}, 6000);  //el segundo se hace invisble después de 3 segundos.
    setTimeout(function(){visible(boton)}, 6000);  //el tercero se hace visible cuando pasan 3 segundos.
    setTimeout(function(){invisible(boton)}, 9000);  //el tercero se hace invisble después de 3 segundos.
    
}

function visible(span){ //función para hacer visibles los elementos span o otros elementos se puede utilizar para toda la página
    span.style.display = "block"; 
}

function invisible(span){  //función para hacer invisibles los elementos span o otros elementos se puede utilizar para toda la página
    span.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
div{
    height: 40px; //si no el siguiente div o el boton ocuparía su espacio
    background: #5c8ee0; //si no los divs serían transparentes y no se visualizarian
    margin: 10px; //si no los divs se verían juntos haciendo 1 solo cuadrado de color azul
  }
span{
    display:none; //los elementos no aparecen cuando carga la página.
  }
```

```html
    <div>
      <span id="input1">input 1 (necesito un mensaje por unos segundos)</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span id="input2">input 2 (necesito otro mensaje por unos segundos)</span>
    </div>

    <button>Boton  <span id="boton">
    boton(necesito el ultimo mensaje por unos segundos)
    </span></button>
```

Sinceramente tal y como lo he hecho es lo más simple posible(en mi opinión), es bastante mejorable, pero no tengo mucho tiempo ahora.

Espero que te sirva.

---

Actualización, con librería Intro.js:

```css
div, button{
        height: 40px; /*si no el siguiente div o el boton ocuparía su espacio*/
        /*background: #5c8ee0; si no los divs serían transparentes y no se visualizarian*/
        margin: 10px; /*si no los divs se verían juntos haciendo 1 solo cuadrado de color azul*/
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="introjs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="prueba.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="step1">
      <h1>Este es el primer div</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="step2">
            <h1>Este es el segundo div</h1>
        </div>

        <button id="step3">Boton</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="intro.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = startIntro();
  function startIntro(){
  var intro = introJs();
     intro.setOptions({
         steps: [
            {
              element: '#step1',
              intro: "input 1 (necesito un mensaje por unos segundos)"
              },
              {
                element: '#step2',
                intro: "input 2 (necesito otro mensaje por unos segundos)"
              },
              {
                element: '#step3',
                intro: "boton(necesito el ultimo mensaje por unos segundos)",
                position: 'right'
              }
            ]
          });

          intro.start();
      }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Demostración del resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Fallos que he visto de esta librería:

No puedes acceder por ruta, si no que tienes que descargarte el css y js desde su página web, además de que los textos no se ajustan exactos.

- Puntos favorables:

Es facíl de utilizar, herramientas de navegación entre los elementos de la página y visualmente es agradable.

> Recuerda: A la hora de ejecutarse aquí no funcionarán, porque tienes
>   que importar la librería a tú ordenador y indicar la ruta en tú
>   fichero html tanto del css como del js.

Comment: encontre esta libreria https://introjs.com/

Comment: Oh! vale ahora te muestro un ejemplo con esta librería. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sin librerías puedes hacer algo sencillo, pero mejor si añades transiciones y otros efectos. Para el ejemplo básico solo necesitas un bucle que muestre la secuencia de mensajes y vaya esperando un tiempo entre ellos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }

        async function demo(messages) {
            console.log('Begining test...');

            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                await sleep(1500);

                var msg = messages[i];
                console.log('The message is: ' + msg);
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
            }

            // To dissapear the last message
            await sleep(1500);
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Test of secuencial messages</h1>

    <p>Message:</p>
    <div class="message" id="message">lala</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var messages = [
            'first message',
            'second message',
            'and one more...',
            'the last one'
        ];
        demo(messages);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sustituyendo el script principal por el siguiente (incluye pausas sin contenido entre mensajes) el resultado visual mejora bastante sin complicar las cosas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    function setMessage(msg) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
    }

    async function demo(messages) {
        // console.log('Begining test...');

        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            setMessage('');
            await sleep(500);

            var msg = messages[i];
            // console.log('The message is: ' + msg);
            setMessage(msg);

            await sleep(2000);
        }

        // To dissapear the last message
        setMessage('');
    }
</script>
```